# Identification of the most frequently used words within string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My challenge for today is: how to find let’s say three the most frequently used words within string field.
Know how extract the occurrence of particular word (below) but how to identify 3 the most frequently used ones?
I would appreciate any suggestion on that.

Regards,
Arek

```
declare @string varchar(max)
set @string = 'mouse cat dog elephant chicken cat dog elephant cat dog elephant cat dog cat elephant cat lion dog elephant cat dog elephant lion cat dog elephant cat dog elephant cat dog elephant cat dog cat dog cat dog chicken lion'

select (DATALENGTH(@string) - DATALENGTH(REPLACE(@string, 'cat', '')))/DATALENGTH('cat')
```

Comment: Have you considered what would or should happen if `@string` contains `bobcat`?

Comment: The first part of this problem requires that you split the string into "words" based on a delimited, in this case `' '` (a space). Then you do some basic aggregation to find which three "words" have the highest number of occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a string splitting function. Depending on your version of SQL Server you can either use your own function(one is included below) or the built in `string_split`, which is available from 2016 onwards:

```
declare @string varchar(max);
set @string = 'mouse cat dog elephant chicken cat dog elephant cat dog elephant cat dog cat elephant cat lion dog elephant cat dog elephant lion cat dog elephant cat dog elephant cat dog elephant cat dog cat dog cat dog chicken lion';

-- via user defined TVF
select item as word
    ,count(1) as frequency
from dbo.fn_stringsplit4k(@string,' ',null) as s
group by item
order by frequency desc;

-- via built in STRING_SPLIT function
select s.value as word
    ,count(1) as frequency
from string_split(@string,' ') as s
group by s.value
order by frequency desc;
```

## Output

```
+----------+-----------+
|   word   | frequency |
+----------+-----------+
| cat      |        13 |
| dog      |        12 |
| elephant |         9 |
| lion     |         3 |
| chicken  |         2 |
| mouse    |         1 |
+----------+-----------+
```

## Table Valued Function

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fn_StringSplit4k]
(
     @str nvarchar(4000) = ' '              -- String to split.
    ,@delimiter as nvarchar(1) = ','        -- Delimiting value to split on.
    ,@num as int = null                     -- Which value to return.
)
returns table
as
return
                    -- Start tally table with 10 rows.
    with n(n)   as (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1)

                    -- Select the same number of rows as characters in @str as incremental row numbers.
                    -- Cross joins increase exponentially to a max possible 10,000 rows to cover largest @str length.
        ,t(t)   as (select top (select len(isnull(@str,'')) a) row_number() over (order by (select null)) from n n1,n n2,n n3,n n4)

                    -- Return the position of every value that follows the specified delimiter.
        ,s(s)   as (select 1 union all select t+1 from t where substring(isnull(@str,''),t,1) = @delimiter)

                    -- Return the start and length of every value, to use in the SUBSTRING function.
                    -- ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the last value where there is no delimiter at the end of the string.
        ,l(s,l) as (select s,isnull(nullif(charindex(@delimiter,isnull(@str,''),s),0)-s,4000) from s)

    select rn
          ,item
    from(select row_number() over(order by s) as rn
                ,substring(@str,s,l) as item
        from l
        ) a
    where rn = @num
        or @num is null;
```

Comment: Doh, I didn't notice you already posted Jeff Moden's DelimitedSplit function. I've leave my answer up since I posted the `VARCHAR` version and yours is the `NVARCHAR` version.

Comment: @digital.aaron  Mine is a tailored version based on my needs.  It is not entirely the same as Jeff Moden's

Answer (score 1):

Easy :)

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @strngLen int
DECLARE @split TABLE(w_id INT IDENTITY(1,1),w_word VARCHAR(100))
set @string = 'mouse cat dog elephant chicken cat dog elephant cat dog elephant cat dog cat elephant cat lion dog elephant cat dog elephant lion cat dog elephant cat dog elephant cat dog elephant cat dog cat dog cat dog chicken lion'
SET @strngLen = CHARINDEX(' ', @String)

WHILE CHARINDEX(' ', @String) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @strngLen = CHARINDEX(' ', @String);

    INSERT INTO @split
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,1,@strngLen - 1);

    SET @String = SUBSTRING(@String, @strngLen + 1, LEN(@String));
END

INSERT INTO @split
SELECT @String

SELECT w_word, COUNT(1) FROM @split
GROUP BY w_word
ORDER BY COUNT(1) desc
```

Comment: This will perform very slowly compared to a set based solution.

Comment: it might be slower, but then again it might not be - has anyone tested it?  XML stuff seems to grab a lot of CPU I experienced.  Split is presumably optimised in lower level code, but it doesn't exist in all SQL versions, I seem to recall it's fairly new.

Comment: Yeah, actually, someone has done a LOT of testing on string splitting... http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: This is probably the worst possible way to split a string in SQL. And yes, [someone have tested it.](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) For 2016 versions or higher, the built in string_split outperforms any user defined function out there, including clr based.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with SQL Server 2016 you can use STRING_SPLIT for this kind of stuff:

```
SELECT
  value      AS word
  , COUNT(*) AS occurrence 
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@string, ' ')
GROUP BY value
ORDER BY occurrence DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are good answers already. So this is more like showing the huge variety of approaches we can find. This is an `XQuery` approach:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @string = 'mouse cat dog elephant chicken cat dog elephant cat dog elephant cat dog cat elephant cat lion dog elephant cat dog elephant lion cat dog elephant cat dog elephant cat dog elephant cat dog cat dog cat dog chicken lion'


SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@string,' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
      .query('
            for $word in distinct-values(/x)
            return <word value="{$word}" count="{count(/x[text()=$word])}"/>
           ');
```

The result

```
  <word value="mouse" count="1" />
  <word value="cat" count="13" />
  <word value="dog" count="12" />
  <word value="chicken" count="2" />
  <word value="lion" count="3" />
  <word value="elephant" count="9" />
```

Of course it would be easy to get this result in tabular form...

### Some enhancement - just for fun

This will return just the three top counts:

```
SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@string,' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
    .query('
            for $word in distinct-values(/x)
            let $wCount:=count(/x[text()=$word])
            order by $wCount descending
            return <word value="{$word}" count="{$wCount}"/>
        ')
    .query('for $i in(1,2,3) return /word[$i]')
```

The result

```
<word value="cat" count="13" />
<word value="dog" count="12" />
<word value="elephant" count="9" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great opportunity to share an awesome solution I've found for this exact problem. It's uses [Jeff Moden's](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) excellent DelimitedSplit8k function.

First, the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.

SELECT a.ItemNumber,
vn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Item ORDER BY a.ItemNumber asc),
a.Item 
FROM 
( SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l) a
GO
```

The function uses a "numbers" or "tally" table to split a string very quickly, and as a set-based operation.

Now here's how to use it:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(8000)

SET @string = 'mouse cat dog elephant chicken cat dog elephant cat dog elephant cat dog cat elephant cat lion dog elephant cat dog elephant lion cat dog elephant cat dog elephant cat dog elephant cat dog cat dog cat dog chicken lion'

SELECT TOP 3
    Item
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@string, ' ')
GROUP BY Item
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Output:

```
Item
----
cat
dog
elephant
```